# Why is my code outputting strings multiple times in my if statement?

Tags: c#, text, console

My code outputs the same string multiple times. For example, typing in 40 results in "Nope! Your answer is too high. Try again." twice, and it displays "your answer is too low" twice.

```
while (numberguess != 40.5)
{
    numberguess = Console.Read();
    if (numberguess < 40.5)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Nope! Your answer is too low. Try again.");

    }
    else if (numberguess > 40.5)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Nope! Your answer is too high. Try again.");
    }
    else if (numberguess == 40.5)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Correct! Wow, I didn't really think you would figure it out!");
        break;
    }
}
```

I expect only one string to show up when typing in a number, and I want it to correspond to whether it is lower or higher than a particular number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several problems with this single line:

```
numberguess = Console.Read();
```

First this returns an int, so it will never return 40.5. Also this reads one character at a time, including the ones input by the enter key, so when you type 40 and press Enter it reads '4', then '0' then '\r' and finally '\n' (converting those chars to int). That's why it displays four messages.

Instead you have to read everything typed before the Enter with `Console.ReadLine()` and then convert this (string) to a double. So in the end you have to do this:

```
numberguess = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
```

Comment: @AlexanderSummers Now try entering something that won't parse.

Answer (score 1):

Console.Read() reads a single character as an int. If you're trying to get what the user typed before they hit enter, read the current line, and then parse an integer from it.

```
int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
```

Comment: Better use int.TryParse when dealing with uncertain user inputs

Comment: Thanks, but I want to keep it as a double. How would I do that?

Comment: Parse and TryParse are available also for the double type.